# Converting a .tib image to a vm using powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, powercli

Does anyone know of any ways to automate the conversion of a .tib to a virtual machine file? I am looking to have a service that will automate the conversion process for my .tib files.

So far, the best solution that i found was using VMware PowerCLI, but it seems that you need access to their servers in order to use the actual conversion cmdlet (unless i am doing something wrong). If anyone has anymore information please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VMware's standalone Converter [can](http://www.vmware.com/support/converter/doc/conv_sa_51_rel_notes.html) convert from some .tib versions and has an [API](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/developer/forums/convertersdk), which I've never used.

I'm curious how you're doing this in PowerCLI.

edit - The Standalone Converter supports VMware Player and Workstation as destinations. See p20 [here](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/convsa_51_guide.pdf). So no, I don't think you need a full-fledged server installation to use this.

Comment: I have looked into VMware Standalone Converter before, but don't you need to use their servers in order to convert files to VMs? From my understanding, PowerCLI has a set of Cmdlets that you can use for the conversion process. What i was thinking about doing is using the Cmdlets and putting them into a function in a PowerShell script and then calling the function from my windows service. But again, it seems that using a VMware server costs money. Am i thinking about this the wrong way or do you know of another way?

Comment: So you think i will be able to convert my .tib file to a VM using their API?

Comment: Dunno, but I've been told: virtually everything is poshable.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help. I am going to take a look into their API and see what I can do for free. Thank you!